# Binding combobox BindingList Winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, binding, combobox

Ok, so I have been facing this issue several times now but I always seemed to figure it out.
This time, ive been stuck and ive tried multiple things, but nothing is working.

I have a `combobox` of customers in a customer form. When i create a new customer, my `combobox` is not updating. It only refreshes when closing and re-opening the form.
I am aware of the "ugly and quick" solutions, but I don't want to use this unless I have no other choise. So ive been using `BindingLists` because of the events... BUT this is not working in my case.

Ive been staring to this for a time now, let it aside, tried again, but keep on failing.

Does anyone know whats missing in this puzzle?

Now the code: Presenter

```
 public class CustomerPresenter
{

   private tbl_customer customer = new tbl_customer();
   private CustomerView customerView = new CustomerView();


   public CustomerPresenter(tbl_customer customer, CustomerView customerView)

   {
       this.customer = customer;
       this.customerView = customerView;
       customerView.customerPresenter = this;
   }
  // Get a list of customers
   public List<tbl_customer> customerList;
   public BindingList<tbl_customer> getCustomers()
   {        
       using (var customers = new DBCrownfishEntities())
       {
           var customer = from c in customers.tbl_customer
                          where c.IsDeleted == false
                          select c;

           this.customerList = customer.ToList();
           var listBinding = new BindingList<tbl_customer>(this.customerList);
           return listBinding;
         }

    }
 public void testAdd() 
   {
       tbl_customer customer = new tbl_customer();
       customer.CustomerPrefix = "Pref";
       customer.CustomerName = "Name";
       customer.CustomerAddress = "Address";
       customer.CustomerPostalCode = "1111";
       customer.CustomerCity = "City";
       customer.CustomerCountry = "Country";
       customer.CustomerCountryCode = "BE";
       customer.CustomerVat = "123456789";
       customer.hasVatNumber = true;


   try
    {
     using (var cust = new DBCrownfishEntities())
                   {
                       cust.tbl_customer.Add(customer);
                       cust.SaveChanges();
                       MessageBox.Show("A new customer is succesfully added!");
                   }
               }
               catch (EntityException exception)
               {
                   MessageBox.Show(exception.InnerException.Message.ToString(), "Error Connecting database");


               } 
               catch (Exception)
               {

                   throw;
               }
   }
}
```

View:

```
BindingSource bsCustomers = new BindingSource();

private void CustomerView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bsCustomers.DataSource = customerPresenter.getCustomers();
    cbCustomers.DataSource = bsCustomers;
    cbCustomers.DisplayMember = "CustomerName";
    cbCustomers.ValueMember = "CustomerId";
    radioButton1_CheckedChanged(null, null);
}


private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            customerPresenter.testAdd();
        }
```

Model:

```
public partial class tbl_customer
{
    public tbl_customer()
    {
        this.tbl_invoices = new HashSet<tbl_invoices>();
    }

    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerPrefix { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerEmailaddress { get; set; }
    public string CustomerAddress { get; set; }
    public string CustomerPostalCode { get; set; }
    public string CustomerCity { get; set; }
    public string CustomerVat { get; set; }
    public string CustomerCountryCode { get; set; }
    public string CustomerCountry { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public bool hasVatNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<tbl_invoices> tbl_invoices { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: We could help better if you provide [mcve].

Comment: @Ivan Stoev: well i would be glad to provide you with that, but thats not an easy one. But i'll try and edit it

Comment: Code edited. Im using entity framework, thats why im not sure its easy to put complete and verifiable example of the code

Comment: @Reza I was indeed to fast pressing the save button. I was still updating it while you were replying i think

Comment: The point is that you need to add it to the binding list.

Comment: :) I saw your edit so I removed my previous comment. Now you can expect the customer be added to database, **but still it's not present in BindingSource**. You should reload data and fill the `BindingSource` again or add it also to the `BindingList` which is the `DataSource` of `BindingSource`.

Comment: So, i was basicly correct the whole time thinking I need to reload the datasource after the customerPresenter.testAdd(); in my case? Or adding my bindingsource to the list. But then I can not know if its a new item or an existing item in the database, or i need to loop through it and check wich ID already exists ?

Comment: I don't have any Idea about how can it be an existing customer. But after you added the new item to database, you have two options, reload data, or add the item also to the binding list which is data source of your binding source.